# Why was Ben Affleck cast as Batman instead of keeping Christian Bale?

Tags: casting, dc-extended-universe

I'm not trying to spark discussion; I just want to know if there was a specific reason the actors changed. I have a high opinion of Christian Bale's acting; I figured DC wouldn't want to change timelines like that unnecessarily.

Comment: Bale / Snyder weren't willing!

Comment: First of all, completely changing your question into something else is not really a good idea. If you have a new question, feel free to ask a new question. But I'm afraid that new question also isn't really answerable in a non-opinionated way.